# Date string Manipulation

Tags: mysql, string, date

My current input table looks like below

```
Current_Day billing_day
Oct-13      14
Oct-13      15
Oct-13      16
Oct-13       1
Oct-13       8
Oct-13      12
```

I want the resultant table to look as below

```
Current_Day billing_day Start_date  End_date
Oct-13      14          Oct-13      oct-14
Oct-13      15          Oct-13      oct-15
Oct-13      16          Oct-13      oct-16
Oct-13       1          Oct-13      nov-1
Oct-13       8          Oct-13      nov-8
Oct-13      12          Oct-13      nov-12
```

Is there a way or a function to achieve this in MySQL?

Edit:

If the billing_day is 14, it should show nearest upcoming calendar date
Ex: 14 means oct-14, 1 means Nov-1 since oct-1 has already passed.

resultant End_date should not be the addition of billing_day + Current_day

It should follow the current calendar

Comment: Where does the `End_date` come from? OK. Got it. Do you want to update this in the table or just to show?

Comment: End_date has to be derived from billing_day, for ex:14 becomes oct-14

Comment: Show and Update to the table :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In database don't use String to represent date you should use TimeStamp.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Function Date and Time

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html